# Problem trying to set a column value in a temp table to an empty string

Tags: t-sql

Currently in an SP, we have columns created in a temp table that are being set to 0 by default using the first SET statement below but I am now needing the columns to be set to an empty string value and not null:

```
SET @columns =  @columns + ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' [' + cast((@i+1) as nvarchar) +  '] int Default 0' SET @i = @i + 1;
```

I tried using this solution:

```
SET @columns = @columns + ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +  ' [' + cast((@i+1) as nvarchar) + '] nvarchar Default []' SET @i = @i+1;
```

but when I create the ALTER statement:

```
Alter TABLE #Survivaltmp Add ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, '') + ''
```

that adds the column with stuffing this variable I am getting this error:

An object or column name is missing. For Select Into statements verify each column has a name.
My question is, is there any way to add an empty string value to a column?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are enclosed in single quotes, not brackets, they're for identifiers.

Try:

```
... + '] nvarchar Default ''''' ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help.  It's appreciated.